# No overload for method '' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

Well, my issue here is basically what it says in the title. I'm trying to call my bool value of my Player2 class for my Tic Tac Toe-project we have in school. I think it's worth mentioning that I use "Player Player1, Player2;" in the beginning of Form1.cs to create two instances of my class, Player. I've read multiple posts on the internet about this but all of them are people trying to call in more parameters than that they are providing. I don't see how a bool value of true or false is more than one.

Thanks in advance.

> One of my buttons where this problem appears.

```
public void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) >{

        {
            if (click1 == 0) 
            {
            if (Player2.GetActive(true))//(turn == 0)
                {
                 Btn1.Text = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    >Btn1.Text = "O";
                }
                //turn++;
                click1++;
            }
            else
            {
                Btn1.Text = Btn1.Text;
           }
            display();
            checkit();
       }
    }
```

> This is my player class.

```
` public class Player
{
    //Characteristics
    string name;
    int points;
    bool Active;

    //Constructor
    public Player() { points = 0; Active = true; }

    //Methods
    public void SetName(string n) { name = n; }
    public string GetName() { return name; }
    public void SetPoints(int p) { points = p; }
    public int GetPoints() { return points; }
    public void SetActive(bool a) { Active = a; }
    public bool GetActive() { return Active; }`
```

Comment: You're calling `GetActive` and passing in a `bool`.  But the definition for your `GetActive` method doesn't take any arguments:  `public bool GetActive() { return Active; }`

Comment: Also forgot mentioning that I'm very new to programming. Programming is one of the courses in my high school program so I'm not studying on a university or anything as I'm only 17.

Comment: @JonatanSvedisSvedberg Just change it to `if (Player2.GetActive())`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that what you are trying to accomplish with `GetActive()` could be accomplished with a public property, if you want it to be get only you could have the set be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```
if(Player2.GetActive(true))
```

you are passing an extra argument (`true`) to the method `GetActive`. As we can see from the method declaration of `GetActive`, it takes no parameters:

```
public bool GetActive() { return Active; }
//                   ↑
//              empty parentheses
```

I think what you mean here is "if `Player2.GetActive()` is true..." right? You don't need to specify the value you want if it is `true`, just doing this is fine:

```
if (Player2.GetActive())
```

If you want to check if it is false, add `!` before the call to negate the result:

```
if (!Player2.GetActive())
```

Comment: @JonatanSvedisSvedberg If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: I know this is kinda off topic but I'm wondering if you know a simple way of randomizing which one of Player1 or Player2 should be active and the other one not?

Comment: @JonatanSvedisSvedberg search on google for `System.Random` first. If you can't find anything that helps, go to stack overflow documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You have the code:

```
Player2.GetActive(true)
```

But you define get active as

```
public bool GetActive() { return Active; }`
```

So it is correct you have not defined a GetActive with a parameter.

Comment: How can I solve this then? As you might have noticed, I'm a very novice programmer.

Comment: Dont pass true, just call Player2.GetActive()

Answer (score 0):

Like BugFinder said, you are using the method to get the Active-Value instead of using the method to set the value.

So change

```
Player2.GetActive(true)
```

to

```
Player2.SetActive(true)
```

Just as an addition:
Since we are working with C# here and many of your methods are called set and get, I suggest you change those methods to be properties:

```
public string Name 
{
  get { return name; }
  set { name = value; }
}

public int Points 
{
  get { return points; }
  set { points = value; }
}

public bool Active 
{
  get { return active; }
  set { active = value; }
}
```

Now when you want to set the value, you can type

```
Player2.IsActive = true;
```

and to check the value simple type code like

```
If(Player2.IsActive)
  //Do Stuff
```